# Enable an asp.net core web application to work without internet and with internet?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have been developing an asp.net core web application and published on the production mode (online server), the users can access it with the specific domain name and will log in and do data entry from three different countries.
But, the problem is sometimes, in one specific country there is no internet access, my client wants that this application should work online and offline, If there is no internet access the local branch must be able to do data entry, then when the internet gets connected data should send to the online server database,

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Please write your view or add some good forum link below.

Comment: Thats a massive question, and unfortunately not suited to StackOverflow as SO deals with specific technical issues. You'll need to research replicated systems e.g. https://selmatic-pos.com/index.php/technical-architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Rationally, it is not possible for you to access a **Web App** without internet. Web Apps are meant for network usage. However, I believe there is a workaround for such requirements. What you can do is that you can create a **clone** of your database for the third user, who has no internet access and perform all transactions within the local machine and when the connection comes back on line, you can replicate the data from the local SQL Server into the online server database.

And then there is something called [`Progressive Web Apps`](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/introduction-to-pwa-in-asp-net-core-application-da96c7cc4918) , which will allow you below privileges :

- **Reliable** - Load instantly and never show the downasaur, even in uncertain network conditions.
- **Fast** - Respond quickly to user interactions with silky smooth animations and no janky
- **Engaging** - Feel like a natural app on the device, with an immersive user experience.

What are **Progressive Web Applications**, Google has something more to discuss [here](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)